# Symbol's value as variable is void: eclimd-port

Tags: eclim

After Following the installation guidelines of [emacs-eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim#installation) I wanted to start eclimd by "start-eclimd" but the following error message pops up in the Mini-Buffer.

> Symbol's value as variable is void: eclimd-port

Eclimd script works flawless when started in eclipse.

Running the script in the shell gives me the following error:

> Your jvm does not support the architecture required  for the version of eclipse you have installed: -d32

My Java version:

> java version "1.7.0_21"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

is this an 64-Bit issue?

I just want to have control over the daemon within emacs or at least the script.
These lines are relevant in my .emacs:

```
;; Eclim - eclipse interface for emacs
(require 'eclim)
(global-eclim-mode)
(require 'eclimd)
```

full stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable eclimd-port)
  (let ((eclimd-start-regexp "Eclim Server Started on\\(?: port\\|:\\) \\(?:\\(?:[0-9]+\\.\\)\\{3\\}[0-9]+:\\)?\\([0-9]+\\)")) (save-match-data (let ((output (eclimd--match-process-output eclimd-start-regexp eclimd-process))) (when output (setq eclimd-port (match-string 1 output)) (message (concat "eclimd serving at port " eclimd-port))))) eclimd-port)
  wait-eclimd-start()
  (progn (wait-eclimd-start))
  (if eclimd-wait-for-process (progn (wait-eclimd-start)))
  (when eclimd-wait-for-process (wait-eclimd-start))
  (if (eclimd--running-p) (message "Cannot start eclimd: eclimd is already running.") (message (concat "Starting eclimd for workspace: " workspace-dir "...")) (setq eclimd-process-buffer (make-comint eclimd-process-buffer-name eclimd-prog nil (concat "-Dosgi.instance.area.default=" (replace-regexp-in-string "~" "@user.home" workspace-dir)))) (setq eclimd-process (get-buffer-process eclimd-process-buffer)) (when eclimd-wait-for-process (wait-eclimd-start)))
  (if (not eclimd-prog) (message "Cannot start eclimd: check eclimd-executable variable.") (if (eclimd--running-p) (message "Cannot start eclimd: eclimd is already running.") (message (concat "Starting eclimd for workspace: " workspace-dir "...")) (setq eclimd-process-buffer (make-comint eclimd-process-buffer-name eclimd-prog nil (concat "-Dosgi.instance.area.default=" (replace-regexp-in-string "~" "@user.home" workspace-dir)))) (setq eclimd-process (get-buffer-process eclimd-process-buffer)) (when eclimd-wait-for-process (wait-eclimd-start))))
  (let ((eclimd-prog (eclimd--executable-path))) (if (not eclimd-prog) (message "Cannot start eclimd: check eclimd-executable variable.") (if (eclimd--running-p) (message "Cannot start eclimd: eclimd is already running.") (message (concat "Starting eclimd for workspace: " workspace-dir "...")) (setq eclimd-process-buffer (make-comint eclimd-process-buffer-name eclimd-prog nil (concat "-Dosgi.instance.area.default=" (replace-regexp-in-string "~" "@user.home" workspace-dir)))) (setq eclimd-process (get-buffer-process eclimd-process-buffer)) (when eclimd-wait-for-process (wait-eclimd-start)))))
  start-eclimd("~/workspace")
  call-interactively(start-eclimd t nil)
  execute-extended-command(nil)
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Could you give a full stack trace? `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` before you require eclim and eclimd.

Comment: I think added what you wanted! Total Emacs beginner here.

Comment: It seems like this happens when eclimd crashes before it has a chance to print the port it's listening on.  There might be some clues in the `eclimd` buffer, but if I'm reading the code correctly, `eclimd--match-process-output` would throw away any interesting error messages...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug in the eclimd.el file (~/.emacs.d/elpa/emacs-eclim-20140809.207/eclimd.el)

I added a defvar for eclimd-port and that resolved this issue. (reported here:https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim/issues/156)

```
    (defvar eclimd-port nil
      "The active eclimd port number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not an emacs issue. When you run `start-eclimd` on emacs, it probably fires off a process using the same context as when you run the script from the shell, where you get the 32- vs. 64-bit error.

Perhaps you should try to fix your eclim setup so that when you run it from the shell you get an output that looks like

> Eclim Server Started on port ...

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/eclim-user/DCaUxoRcI_k) might help.

Comment: built it from source with fix etc. didn't help